# Problem with Laser Scanner hokuyo URG-04LX-UG01 in ROS hydro

Tags: rviz, laser, rosbag, ros-hydro, scanner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to run a laser scanner in ROS hydro. First of all I can connect to laser via hokuyo_node. But when I want to visit output data with RVIS, I can't! when I add laserscanner and change topic to scan , status changes to error.
And also I try to log data with "rosbag record -O name /scan". But unfortunately I faced to this error:

/opt/ros/hydro/lib/rosbag/record: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosbag.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPN7log4cxx6LoggerENS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS9_S9_z

I try: "apt-get update"    and    "apt-get upgrade"

but it doesn't work yet! What can I do now?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/146351/problem-with-laser-scanner-hokuyo-urg-04lx-ug01-in-ros-hydro/) by [adroit89](https://answers.ros.org/users/14081/adroit89/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-30**:
What does "doesn't work" mean exactly? What errors do you get for apt-get and when you set the laser display in rviz?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-30**:
The error that you see might be fixable with apt-get upgrade.

**Comment by [adroit89](https://answers.ros.org/users/14081/adroit89/) on 2014-03-31**:
I meant that even after upgrade, rosbag doesn't work. But now I can solve problem with rosbag by another solution in this link "http://answers.ros.org/question/123421/hydro-kinect-ubuntu-1204-library-issue/"

I run roscore and then hokuyo_node and then rvis and I set laser scanner and topic scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're hitting the same symbol error / ABI breakage with rosbag that many other users are seeing. Try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to upgrade everything.

I suspect the problem that you're seeing in rviz is due to a frame mismatch. You should be able to expand the topic and the error message to confirm this. By default, the hokuyo_node publishes sensor data in the `laser` frame; try changing your rviz fixed frame to `laser`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2